# What does this Release Modifier do?

Tags: python, xlib

I am currently programming a Window Manager for X11 using python-xlib. So far, I used myself the [Simplewm](http://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2011/03/28/how-to-write-a-window-manager-in-python/) by Sqizit as an orientation, which is orientated at [PLWM](http://plwm.sourceforge.net/).

And in both WMs, you can find a Release Modifier, which is defined as

```
RELEASE_MODIFIER = Xlib.X.AnyModifier << 1
```

But in both, there is no further explanation about what exactly this modifier does. I haven't found anything on Google either.

So, if any Xlib-Expert could explain to me what this thing is (I think it should be understandable for C Programmers as well), I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reference I could find is in the [Sawfish WM programming manual](http://sawmill.sourceforge.net/prog-manual.html), which says

> There are two special modifiers: the Any prefix matches any set of
>   modifiers; the Release modifier matches key-release events instead of
>   the default key-presses.